# Using a class initiated in one method in another method

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, methods

I have a C# WPF app that every time the user opens a new file, the contents are displayed in a datagrid.

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
     public TabControl tc = new TabControl();

     public MainWindow()
     {
         InitializeComponents();
     }

     private FromFile_click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {
         //gets information from file and then...

         if (numberOfFiles == 0)
         {
             masterGrid.Children.Add(tc);
         }
         TabItem ti = new TabItem();
         tc.Items.Add(ti);

         DataGrid dg = new DataGrid();
         ti.Content = dg;

         dg.Name = "Grid"+ ++numberOfFiles;

         dg.ItemSource = data;
     }

     private otherMethod(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
     {

     }
}
```

My question is, how do I use the data in dg in the method "otherMethod"? Also, is it possible to change the parent of dg from the method "otherMethod"?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming you're not calling `otherMethod` within `FromFile_Click`, you need to make it an instance variable - like your `TabControl` is, except hopefully not public. I'm assuming `otherMethod` is actually meant to handle an event of some kind, rather than being called directly.

Now this is assuming that you want one `DataGrid` per instance of `MainWindow`, associated with that window. If that's not the case, you'd need to provide more information.

Comment: 'otherMethod' is meant to handle an event, some sort of button click I haven't defined yet. See, I can't make 'TabItem' or 'datagrid' an instance variable because I don't know how many files the user open.

Comment: @anon: So if there could be two datagrids open, which one would you want `otherMethod` to refer to? If you can work *that* out, the rest may well become clear.

Comment: What I'm trying to do is, change tabs into tile view when the user clicks a button. Example: Assume there are several tab open, each one has a datagrid with independent data. If the user clicks a button, then each of the datagrid will move to a individual tile (so a datagrid, being a child of a tab will change into a child of a tile). `tc` will be hidden, and `tv` (defined below) will become visible. The opposite can also happen.

`private TileViewControl tv = new TileViewControl();` is added below where `tc` is defined.

So i guess, `otherMethod` will refer to all the datagrids.

Comment: Right - so if it's going to refer to *all* the datagrids, just have a `List<DataGrid>` variable instead.

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass it as a parameter to the other method `otherMethod` or make it a member variable.

Answer (score 0):

set the  DataGrid dg as a property instead of declaring inside the FromFile_click.

This way when you assign "dg" it will work from any other method (few restrictions apply)